# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOR

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a html form with a drop down in it. Below is my code:

```
$output[]='<td><select name="qty'.$name.'">'
 for($count=1;$count<=$total;$count+=1) {
     '<option value="'.$count.'">'.$count.'</option>'
}
'</select>
 </td>';
```

Can anyone tell me what might be the issue? Also how can I set default selected value to 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed semicolons :

```
$tmp ='<td><select name="qty'.$name.'">';
for($count=1; $count <= $total; $count+=1) {
     $tmp .= '<option value="'.$count.'"';
     if($count == 1) {
       $tmp .= ' selected="selected"';
     }
     $tmp .= '>'.$count.'</option>';
}
$tmp .= '</select></td>';
$output[] = $tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not posible to use like [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) you are used

```
 <?php $temp='<td><select name="qty'.$name.'">';
  for($count=1;$count<=$total;$count+=1) {
  $temp.= '<option value="'.$count.'">'.$count.'</option>';
  }
  $temp.='</select>
  </td>';

  $output[]=$temp;
 ?>
```